# How to Calculate Antilogarithms Without Using the Log/Anti-Log Table?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, applications

In Logarithms and Antilogarithms,calculation of Logarithms seems easy after knowing the properties,calculation of Antilogs seems entirely difficult without using the Log-Antilog Table.I've tried several conventional methods:

Split it into smaller terms,take approximation of ranges,etc. but it's too tedious and time-consuming for me.Is there perhaps a different method/faster method to calculate the Antilog of a number without using the Log-Antilog Table?

Can anyone please help me on this topic?

PS:I'm not talking about natural logs,just the standard base 10 logs-antilogs.

Comment: Do you know anything about Taylor series? If yes, then why are not they useful?

Comment: What was the point of posting this, instead of just editing the earlier version, Parag?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well I noticed that the tags I had given were not useful.I needed to make the question more clear and concise

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari No,I don't know how the Taylor Series Work.Can the Series be applied here?

Comment: And you could have done all those things by editing, right?

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:elementary-number-theory]?

Comment: @ParagEkbote You are supposed to edit rather than delete and repost.

Comment: @GerryMyerson@Jykri Lahtonen I have resolved the doubt,Thanks but no Thanks!

Comment: Fine. But, in the future, Parag, please use this site the way it's intended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the logarithm as
$$\log_{10}(y)=\lfloor \log_{10}(y)\rfloor +a$$ So
$$y = 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(y)\rfloor } \times 10^a=10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(y)\rfloor } \times e^{a \log_e(10)}$$ Now, with $k=a \log(10)$, use one of the approximations of $e^k$ such as
$$e^k\sim\frac{2+k}{2-k} \qquad \text{or}\qquad e^k\sim\frac{12+6k+k^2}{12-6k+k^2} \qquad \text{or}\qquad e^k\sim \frac{120+60k+12 k^2+k^3}{120-60k+12 k^2-k^3}$$

**Example**

As asked in comments,
$$\log_{10}(y)=5.7=5+0.7 \implies k=0.7\log_e(10)$$ Using the last approximation
$$ e^k\sim \frac{120+60k+12 k^2+k^3}{120-60k+12 k^2-k^3}=5.01343\implies y=5.01343\times 10^5$$

In fact, since $a >0.5$, it is better to work with ceiling
$$\log_{10}(y)=5.7=6-0.3 \implies k=-0.3\log_e(10)$$ Using the last approximation
$$ e^k\sim \frac{120+60k+12 k^2+k^3}{120-60k+12 k^2-k^3}=0.501187\implies y=0.501187\times 10^6=5.01187\times 10^5$$

The exact value is $y=5.01187\times 10^5$

Comment: Here y is the required value right?Also where e^k is being used?

Comment: @ParagEkbote. Sorry, I had  a typo (not $x$ but $y$..

Comment: Padé strikes again

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm Sorry,but can you briefly explain what type of steps you have done in your answer.

Comment: @ParagEkbote. To make an example, give me a value for a logarithm and I shall edit.

Comment: @FShrike. Still kidding the old man about his passion for Padé (.... approximants) ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici let's say antilog(5.7)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Much clearer now,thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes :p